# What is the quickest way to level up damage on raider's axe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

I have a raiders axe with max enchants, with heroic on it and I have ender armor. Also, I have maxed out the strength on it and I have a few talismans. I need to know the quickest/most efficient way to max out the damage on it.

I want to be able to 1 shot at least the 9k health enderman, in future, zealots. So my second question is what talisman and enchants and reforges and anything else that I would need to 1 shot zealots would be?

Talisman are accessories that can be used to boost our stats. The talismen that I use are Speed ring, Gravity talisman and Fire talisman. The game also has pets, which when summoned give stat boosts. I have a Level 35 common griffin.
You could view the different kind of talismen [here](https://hypixel-skyblock.fandom.com/wiki/Accessories) and the different pets [here](https://hypixel-skyblock.fandom.com/wiki/Pets).

Comment: Are you sure that there is a clear need for the new tag [hypixel-skyblock]? I am not saying that it was an incorrect choice, but you created the tag because you thought there was a clear need for this tag, not for the sake of creating tags, correct? I know you have recently gained the tag creation privilege, but it should be used sparingly, and with great thought before you begin to create a tag.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I didn't even know when I got that privilege, usually I don't even see the privileges that I have. I genuinely thought anyone could make tags lol. Also, I thought that just using java edition might make people think about some technical issue, so I thought adding Hypixel skyblock tag would be good. If I should remove it, then I will do so, just tell me if I should.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I think it's a pretty good idea for the tag, because for all intents and purposes Hypixel Skyblock is a modded minecraft with items and rules significantly deviating from vanilla - and so similar to [tag:minecraft-tekkit], [tag:minecraft-feed-the-beast], [tag:minecraft-thaumcraft] it just deserves own tag. In particular I consider myself an advanced vanilla Minecraft player, but none of the terms in OP's question ring a bell, this question is unanswerable for anyone who doesn't know Hypixel's specifics.

Comment: ...at most I'd change it to minecraft-hypixel-skyblock to keep it in line with other mod tags.

Comment: a little more information on what talismans and pet you are using might help. I also would have to agree with SF that hypixel skyblock is nothing like vanilla, theres so much stuff that just isnt in vanilla. also, we need a tag wiki for it now!

Comment: @SF. and Softcode, I agree, We could change it to minecraft-hypixel-skyblock, but I am unable to find an option to do so. Also, I am going to make edits accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more talismans, and to reforge them using the accessory bag reforging. You should also get a high redstone collection to increase the size of your accessory bag, you can also start upgrades for your accessory bag in the community shop. Once you have filled it up with unique talismans go to the reforge anvil and click accessory reforge, I would recommend forceful which gives strength, but hurtful(crit damage) and strong(some of both) are also good.

If you aren't sure what talismans to get, you can buy a few cheap ones from the adventurer npc. There are many other cheap ones you have probably unlocked in collections and didn't even notice!

After your talismans are all set its time to move on to leveling up that pet of yours. If you arent already, do your experiments every day, and if possible download a solver (they are allowed, DSM has a good one) this will help you level your pet up and you can make a decent profit if you get lvl 6 or 7 books in superpairs, allowing you to buy better gear.

Comment: Which talisman to specifically get, as I looked up that website, and I found only 3 for strength and damage, or do you mean I should get all talisman and reforge them to forceful as forceful will add strength?

Comment: Also, what is a solver and how will it help me level up my griffin?

Comment: yes, reforging talismans gives stats, forceful gives strength. A solver allows you to do the experiments perfectly accurate, so you gain more xp so your pet levels up faster.

Comment: @RyugaGod in fact, talimsan reforges are probably the most important part of any build, armor and weapon reforges are also very important.

Comment: thanks! also, I upgraded my fairy souls and now I can crit  8k without pots! I will reforge my talisman and then I will see, thanks for the help.